# Ubuntu dual boot with Windows 7 on two hard disks issue

Tags: hard-drive

I had read the basic guide for ubuntu (12.04) installation alongside windows 7. Apparantly none of them mentioned that it was for use on one disk only. I thought it would be okay and i installed Ubuntu on disk other than the windows one, as stated for THE ONE DISK INSTALLATION. Now, when my PC boots up, it straightaway boots into Ubuntu. I changed by BIOS settings and made the Windows HDD first priority, it says Boot Manager is missing. I have no issues with Ubuntu so far but to be able to use it fully, i have to download and update several drivers which i cannot ( due to limited data plan). What can I do?

Ps.: I later searched for dual boot with 2 HDDs and found it is possible. But any suggestions other than reinstalling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your problem is grub not showing up, then use the following commands:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
```

Where X after the sd is the partition name you installed windows or ubuntu on(Your default HDD)
Then simply do

```
sudo update-grub
```

If this is not your problem, just follow the following link. Hope this helps!

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

(Since you are a new askubuntu user, if my answer or my link solved your problem, dont forget to check that green mark on the side of my answer)